# Mule on Amazon Cloud

Tags: amazon-ec2, mule

I installed Mule Community Server on AWS cloud and it is functioning properly. When I use http end point and invoke Mule services from browser on my Amazon EC2 machine they work. When I access them from outside, the request timeout. The end points are not bound to local host but mapped to 0.0.0.0:8081. I have checked all firewall settings using amaozon security group and set permission for all. Yet it doesnt work. I am able to access the Windows IIS http server on the same machine but not mule on port 8081. Any clues would help.

Comment: If you run netstat do you see anything listening on that port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this doesn't sound rude, but did you disable the windows firewall, or allow 8081 through the windows firewall?

Comment: yes indeed it was.. sorry i had overlooked some port settings and assumed it was open.